# Getting valgrind error for uninitialised bytes when using write function

Tags: c, linux, memory, pipe, valgrind

My program is supposed to communicate with pipes between 4 child processes. The program works, but when checking the program with valgrind, I get the error about char buffer, but the program comes to an end and prints out the right answer. Here is the error:

terminal command: ./prodajnaVerigaAnon 100

```
==12926== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==12926==    at 0x4F22710: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==12926==    by 0x400B4E: main (prodajnaVerigaAnon.c:45)
==12926==  Address 0xfff0007e4 is on thread 1's stack
==12926==  in frame #1, created by main (prodajnaVerigaAnon.c:9)
==12926== 
==12927== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==12927==    at 0x4F22710: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==12927==    by 0x400CCF: main (prodajnaVerigaAnon.c:68)
==12927==  Address 0xfff0007e4 is on thread 1's stack
==12927==  in frame #1, created by main (prodajnaVerigaAnon.c:9)
==12927== 
==12928== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==12928==    at 0x4F22710: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==12928==    by 0x400E58: main (prodajnaVerigaAnon.c:92)
==12928==  Address 0xfff0007e4 is on thread 1's stack
==12928==  in frame #1, created by main (prodajnaVerigaAnon.c:9)
==12928== 
156
```

Here is the code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int size = 80;
        int fd1[2];
        int fd2[2];
        int fd3[2];
        char readbuffer[size];

        if(argc > 1) {

            if(pipe(fd1) == -1) {
                perror("tezava pri odpiranju cevi 1");
                return -1;
            }
            if(pipe(fd2) == -1) {
                perror("tezava pri odpiranju cevi 2");
                return -1;
            }
            if(pipe(fd3) == -1) {
                perror("tezava pri odpiranju cevi 3");
                return -1;
            }

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                if(i==0) {
                    switch(fork()) {
                        case 0:
                            close(fd1[0]);

                            close(fd2[0]); 
                            close(fd2[1]);
                            close(fd3[0]);
                            close(fd3[1]);
                            for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
                                char init_price[size];
                                sprintf(init_price,"%d",atoi(argv[i]));
                                write(fd1[1], init_price, size);
                            }
                            close(fd1[1]);
                            _exit(0);

                    }
                }
                else if(i == 1) {
                    switch(fork()) {
                        case 0:
                            close(fd1[1]);

                            close(fd2[0]); 
                            close(fd3[0]);
                            close(fd3[1]);
                            for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
                                read(fd1[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                                int tmp_price = atoi(readbuffer);
                                int fifth_of_price = tmp_price / 5;
                                tmp_price = tmp_price + fifth_of_price;
                                char buffer[size];
                                sprintf(buffer,"%d",tmp_price);
                                write(fd2[1],buffer,size);
                            }

                            close(fd2[1]);
                            close(fd1[0]);
                            _exit(0);
                    }
                }
                else if(i == 2) {
                    switch(fork()) {
                        case 0:
                            close(fd2[1]);

                            close(fd3[0]);
                            close(fd1[0]);
                            close(fd1[1]);

                            for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
                                read(fd2[0],readbuffer,sizeof(readbuffer));
                                int tmp_price = atoi(readbuffer);
                                int third_of_price = tmp_price * 0.3f;
                                tmp_price = tmp_price + third_of_price;
                                char buffer[size];
                                sprintf(buffer,"%d",tmp_price);
                                write(fd3[1],buffer,size);
                            }
                            close(fd3[1]);
                            close(fd2[0]);
                            _exit(0);
                    }
                }
                else if(i == 3) {
                    switch(fork()) {
                        case 0:
                            close(fd3[1]);

                            close(fd1[0]);
                            close(fd1[1]);
                            close(fd2[0]);
                            close(fd2[1]);
                            for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
                                read(fd3[0],readbuffer,sizeof(readbuffer));
                                printf("%s ",readbuffer);
                                fflush(stdout);
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                            close(fd3[0]);
                            _exit(0);

                    }
                }
            }

            close(fd1[0]); 
            close(fd1[1]);
            close(fd2[0]);
            close(fd2[1]);
            close(fd3[0]);
            close(fd3[1]);

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                wait(NULL);
            }


        }
        else {
            printf("Missing input arguments. Usage:\n./prodajnaVerigaAnon <price 1> <price 2> ... <price n>\n");
        }
        return(0);
}
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thank you for your time and effort,

Domen

Comment: `write(fd1[1], init_price, size)` -> `write(fd1[1], init_price, strlen(init_price))`. `size` is the size of the buffer (80 here) and `strlen(init_price)` is the length of the string. Maybe you need `write(fd1[1], init_price, strlen(init_price) + 1)` if you want the string terminator to be written to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
sprintf(init_price,"%d",atoi(argv[i]));
write(fd1[1], init_price, size);
```

is wrong, it passes `size` which is the full size of the buffer to `write`, but only the first few characters will have been written to by `sprintf()`.

The solution is to capture the return value to know how many:

```
const int len = sprintf(init_price, "%d", atoi(argv[i]));
write(fd1[1], init_price, (size_t) len);
```

If you need the 0-terminator, make the final argument `(size_t) len + 1` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be more convenient to use `fdopen()` to open a stream around the file descriptor, so as to use `fprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` + `strlen()` + `write()`.